# Add initialization step to Rails 3 boot process only in server mode

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-plugins

According to http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/Rails/Railtie.html, if I write a Rails 3 plugin and I want to hook into the initialization process, I write

```
class MyRailtie < Rails::Railtie
  initializer "my_railtie.configure_rails_initialization" do
    # some initialization behavior
  end
end
```

However, this initializer appears to be executed when you run, for instance, a Rails `rake` task, not just when you run `rails s` or similar. My question is, how do I prevent my code in this block from being run during Rails tasks, as opposed to full Rails server boot-ups? This seems to be a common problem with Rails 3 plugins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Way back when I posted this question, [Mongoid](http://mongoid.org/) was experiencing this issue. I reported it [here](https://github.com/mongoid/mongoid/issues/285), and it was resolved by wrapping the code in a `config.after_initialize` block. If Rails isn't initialized, then this block is never called. More information [here](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html).

Comment: This does not work for me, whatever code I put in the config.after_initialize gets called even in console mode or rake mode

Comment: Hmm, are you using the same style as in [Mongoid's railtie.rb](https://github.com/mongoid/mongoid/blob/master/lib/mongoid/railtie.rb)? With `config.after_initialize` nested inside of an `initializer` block?

Comment: I put the config.after_initialize block into my application.rb, but the code seems to run everytime no matter if it's launched by rails c or rails s, or even a simple rake

Comment: I also tried to add it in the environment initializer like developement.rb but in this case it seems that it never gets called... :(

Answer (score 4):

add this block to your initializer:

```
if defined?(Rails::Server)
  # do something
end
```

this should work with the current 3.0.6 rails version.

Comment: Hmm, could you say more about the circumstances under which `Rails::Server` is defined? I haven't seen any plugins that use this.

Comment: This is great, but it does not seem to work with Heroku ? Any alternatives ?

Comment: I needed something to use on our dev environment to start up some services but only when run in server mode, went thru the rails source code, that object gets loaded when you start the rails server.